# how to reference a cell that contains the worksheet name to put inside a formula that is inside a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping that someone can help me correct this bit of code not fancy but have been using

```
 Range("D1220:D1243").Formula = "='[ASE Template White Book.xlsx]Cntrl 3'!$D38"
```

to extract information from a closed workbook that is named ASE template White book which is really a saved as copy of a workbook that name will change all the time.  So i have set a refernce document.

through the help here i have manage to extract the worksheet name from the document ref document and put in to the workbook i am working on.

now i am having trouble trying to included the indirect function into the above formula.

```
   Range("A452:A457").Formula = "='[ASE Template White Book.xlsx][=INDIRECT('Tab Names from white book'!&A1&)" '!E16"
```

Range is of a worksheet in my current workbook 
workbook that is refernce [ASE Template White Book]
Sheet name is located on TAb names from white book in side workbook i am working on in this case A1 
E16 is the cell where to start in the reference document

what i am attempting to do is use the cell text which is the sheet name from the ref doc and get it to dynamically change depending on the value in side the cell which is located in column A can someone help i have looked online and the answer on how to use indirect doesn't seem to work when using in the inside the formula i am guessing i am missing some syntax

Also i don't no if possible to include a macro to check if the number in column B is = to a number then ie cell A1 has 2S0 P143 MAIN BUS SECTION cell B1 has  1

as the range where the information will go will depend on the number which is actually an address of an IED which has different Addressing different points

or if there is a way to if the value in column B is equal to then put the information in a1 and b1 in  the corresponding row ie. a6 currently has M751 Bitronics GT5  B6 has the address 33

Comment: Try: `Range("A452:A457").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""'[ASE Template White Book.xlsx]"" & 'Tab Names from white book'!A1 & ""'!E16"")"`

Comment: thank you scott that is brilliant spent the last 3 hours trying to work out my self.  that works but previously when i used with out the indirect excel would take all the data from '!E16 down in the reference white book and match to the range i specified at the beginning of the argument now it just takes the value of E16 and repeats. anyway to have the previous functionality or will have have to specify the reference rage to??